# Haxe abstracts - Can I implicitly cast an array when using @:from?

Tags: casting, haxe

I'm attempting to treat an array of one type as an array of another (abstract) type. It works fine when I use the underlying type of the abstract. But when I attempt implicit conversion using another type (defined using `@:from` keyword), I get a build failure.

It works if I use an explicit `cast`, but I'm wondering - is there any way around this / something I'm missing?

In the example below, I get the build failure `Array<Int> should be Array<StringAbstract>`

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var test:String = "Hello World";
        print(test); //this works

        var testArr:Array<String> = ["Hello", "World"];
        printArray(testArr); //this works (using underlying type)

        var testInt:Int = 10;
        print(testInt); //this works

        var testIntArr:Array<Int> = [1, 2, 3];
        printArray(cast testIntArr);  //this works (explicit cast)
        printArray(testIntArr);  //build failure (using @:from)
    }

    static function print(s:StringAbstract) {
        trace(s);
    }

    static function printArray(arr:Array<StringAbstract>) {
        trace(arr);
    }
}

abstract StringAbstract(String) from String to String {
    inline function new(s:String) {
        this = s;
    }

    @:from
    static public function fromInt(i:Int) {
        return new StringAbstract(Std.string(i));
    }
}
```

---

**Follow Up**

Taking suggestions from Gama11 and Justinfront, I defined an abstract to convert arrays to arrays of my abstract type. But now I'm running into a different issue - as soon as I declare a @:from function, it breaks code that used to work.

Specifically, I used to be able to call my function with "mixed" types that were implicitly converted to the abstract (e.g. `printArray([1, "2", 3]);`).

But as soon as I added a `@:from` function to convert from a different type of array (`Array<Int>` in this case), that functionality broke, with the error `Arrays of mixed types are only allowed if the type is forced to Array<Dynamic>`.

Curious if anyone knows why this would be (example: https://try.haxe.org/#65D03).

```
class Test {
    static function main() {        
        var testMixedArr:Array<StringAbstract> = [1, "2", 3];
        printArray(testMixedArr); //this works
        printArray([1, "2", 3]); //this doesn't work, unless I remove "fromIntArray" function
    }

    static function printArray(arr:StringAbstractArray) {trace(arr);}
}


abstract StringAbstractArray(Array<StringAbstract>) from Array<StringAbstract> to Array<StringAbstract> {
    inline function new(s:Array<StringAbstract>) {
        this = s;
    }

    @:from
    static public function fromIntArray(intArr:Array<Int>) {
        return new StringAbstractArray(Lambda.array( Lambda.map( intArr, function(i: Int):StringAbstract { 
            return i; } )));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way around this is to define an explicit `@:from` function that takes an `Array<Int>`. The reason for this is explained in the [Variance section of the Haxe Manual](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-variance.html). It has a good example of how casting in this case can lead to unsafe code being executed at runtime (rather than being caught by the compiler).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Where would I define said `@:from` function? Do I need to create another abstract?

Comment: You can see @:from for arrays in this code.
https://github.com/nanjizal/triangulations/blob/master/triangulations/Vertices.hx#L125

Comment: Tried implementing these suggestions, and it worked for all my existing examples. But came up with another example that no longer seems to work after adding the new abstract. Updated my original question, if anyone wants to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
printArray( Lambda.array( Lambda.map( testIntArr, function(v: Int):StringAbstract { 
            return v; } )));
```

( No doubt with the new -> stuff it might be cleaner but foundation yet to update mac nightlies so can't play!)

Comment: Also you can create an array abstract to help with the conversion but likely you will still need a loop, you can use  @:forward to get all the normal Array methods.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow up**
This works on try haxe, are you sure you need to even be doing this?

```
 class Test {
    static function main() {        
        var testMixedArr:Array<StringAbstract> = [1, "2", 3];
        printArray(testMixedArr); //this works
        printArray(new StringAbstractArray([1, "2", 3]));
    }

    static function printArray(arr:StringAbstractArray) {
        trace(arr);
    }

}


 abstract StringAbstractArray(Array<StringAbstract>) from Array<StringAbstract> to Array<StringAbstract> {
    inline public function new(s:Array<StringAbstract>) {
        this = s;
    }

    @:from
    static public function fromIntArray(intArr:Array<Int>) {
    return new StringAbstractArray(Lambda.array( Lambda.map( intArr, function(i: Int):StringAbstract { 
        return i; } )));
    }
}


abstract StringAbstract(String) from String to String {
    inline function new(s:String) {
       this = s;
    }

    @:from
    static function fromInt(i:Int) {
        return new StringAbstract(Std.string(i));
    }
}
```

here:

http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#ED866