# Haxe: Using abstracts to define groups of types

Tags: abstract, haxe

I've found out about abstracts in Haxe, and I'm trying to make a sample project to learn how to use them.

So far I've read through: https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html, 
https://haxe.org/blog/abstracting-primitives/, http://old.haxe.org/manual/abstracts, and https://code.haxe.org/category/other/passing-different-types-to-a-function-parameter.html. If anyone has other material they can direct me to, I would appreciate it.

I'm basically trying to make a function that will accept a variable of type `String`, `Int`, `Float`, or `Bool`, and traces it. I've gotten a bit stuck though, when I try to compile with: `haxe -main Main -cpp Export` I get the error: `abstracts/Comparison.hx:99: characters 42-43 : Type not found : A`. I'm trying to find out why this is happening and how to fix it.

I feel like I'm attaching too much code, but this is what I've written so far:

**Main.hx**

```
import abstracts.*;

class Main
{
    public static function main()
    {
        var toPrint:Array<String> = ["String1", "String2", "String3"];
        printArray(toPrint);
    }

    public static function printArray(toPrint:PrintableArray)
    {
        for (element in toPrint)
        {
            trace(element);
        }
    }
}
```

**abstracs/Comparison.hx**

```
package abstracts;

enum Either<A, B>
{
    Left(v:A);
    Right(v:B);
}

abstract Of2<A, B>(Either<A, B>) from Either<A, B> to Either<A, B>
{
    @from inline static function fromA<A, B>(a:A):Of2<A, B>
    {
        return Left(a);
    }
    @from inline static function fromB<A, B>(b:B):Of2<A, B>
    {
        return Right(b);
    }

    @to inline static function toA():Null<A>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Left(a): a;
            default: null;
        }
    }
    @to inline static function toB():Null<B>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Right(b): b;
            default: null;
        }
    }
}

abstract Of3<A, B, C>(Either<Either<A, B>, C>) from Either<Either<A, B>, C> to Either<Either<A, B>, C>
{
    @from inline static function fromA<A, B, C>(a:A):Of3<A, B, C>
    {
        return Left(Left(a));
    }
    @from inline static function fromB<A, B, C>(b:B):Of3<A, B, C>
    {
        return Left(Right(b));
    }
    @from inline static function fromC<A, B, C>(c:C):Of3<A, B, C>
    {
        return Right(c);
    }

    @to inline static function toA():Null<A>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Left(Left(a)): a;
            default: null;
        }
    }
    @to inline static function toB():Null<B>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Left(Right(b)): b;
            default: null;
        }
    }
    @to inline static function toC():Null<C>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Right(c): c;
            default: null;
        }
    }
}

abstract Of4<A, B, C, D>(Either<Either<A, B>, Either<C, D>>) from Either<Either<A, B>, Either<C, D>> to Either<Either<A, B>, Either<C, D>>
{
    @from inline static function fromA<A, B, C, D>(a:A):Of4<A, B, C, D>
    {
        return Left(Left(a));
    }
    @from inline static function fromB<A, B, C, D>(b:B):Of4<A, B, C, D>
    {
        return Left(Right(b));
    }
    @from inline static function fromC<A, B, C, D>(c:C):Of4<A, B, C, D>
    {
        return Right(Left(c));
    }
    @from inline static function fromD<A, B, C, D>(d:D):Of4<A, B, C, D>
    {
        return Right(Right(d));
    }

    @to inline static function toA():Null<A>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Left(Left(a)): a;
            default: null;
        }
    }
    @to inline static function toB():Null<B>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Left(Right(b)): b;
            default: null;
        }
    }
    @to inline static function toC():Null<C>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Right(Left(c)): c;
            default: null;
        }
    }
    @to inline static function toD():Null<D>
    {
        return switch (this)
        {
            case Right(Right(d)): d;
            default: null;
        }
    }
}
```

**abstracts/Printable.hx**

```
package abstracts;

abstract Printable(Comparison.Of4<String, Int, Float, Bool>) {}
```

**abstracts/PrintableArray.hx**

```
package abstracts;

abstract PrintableArray(Array<Printable.Printable>) {}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: I've gotta be honest, **my best advice concerning abstracts is to ignore them**. Unfortunately, it'll take a full blog post to explain why... but the short version is: your codebase will be better off using standard constructs: class inheritance, static extension, functional programming, etc. Abstract enums and abstracting primitives can be good. But when you use abstracts for those temping features (implicit casts, operating overloading, etc), the hidden costs are high. They're not as magic as they appear at first.

Answer (score 1):

The `Type not found : A` error is caused by trying to access the type parameter of a type *instance* in a static function. Static functions only have access to type parameters declared on the function itself. `@:to` methods don't have to be `static`, so you can simply remove the keyword.

There are more problems though:

- You used `@from` and `@to` instead of `@:from` and `@:to`, which means your conversion methods won't have any effect.
- Even when changed to `@:from`, the compiler won't know what to do with `fromA` / `fromB` / `fromC` / `fromD` since they all look the same to him. The type parameters are declared on the static methods, so there's no concrete `String` / `Int` / etc type on which a selection could be based. You might need concrete `fromString` / `fromInt` / etc functions.
- Abstract implicit casts are *not transitive* ([see example at the bottom here](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html)). This means that your `Printable` abstract allows no implicit conversions at all. It could be a simple `typedef` instead:

  ```
  typedef Printable = Comparison.Of4<String, Int, Bool, Float>;
  ```
- Similarly, you can't iterate over a `PrintableArray` without the [`iterator()` method](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-iterators.html) being [forwarded](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-forward.html), for instance with `@:forward(iterator)`. That might lead issues with variance like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823767/haxe-abstracts-can-i-implicitly-cast-an-array-when-using-from) though. You're also missing an implicit conversion `from Array<Printable>` - in short, a `typedef` would be simpler again.
- Even if all of the above is addressed, your `trace()` won't have the desired output. The implicit `@:to` casts aren't applied here since they're a compile time feature, and `trace()` accepts `Dynamic`. You would end up with something like this:

  ```
  source/Main.hx:15: Left(Left(String1))
  ```

  You would have to add a `toString()` method to your abstract to avoid printing the wrapper enums:

  ```
  function toString():String {
      return Std.string(switch this {
          case Left(Left(v)): v;
          case Left(Right(v)): v;
          case Right(Left(v)): v;
          case Right(Right(v)): v;
      });
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm basically trying to make a function that will accept a variable of type `String`, `Int`, `Float`, or `Bool` ...

If this is the core of the issue, you might also look into my [overload](https://lib.haxe.org/p/overload) library. It is a macro that allows function overloading in Haxe. It decides at compile-time, based on the types of the inputs, which of the functions to call. It has some advantages over [`haxe.ds.Either`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/Either.html) (aka `Left` / `Right`), namely it's a compile-time feature with no runtime overhead. And some disadvantages: functions cannot easily be invoked at runtime, or with Dynamic inputs, types must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that works with a bit of runtime overhead:

```
using Type;

class Multimorph {

    public static inline function value ( value : AnyAny ) {
        return value.enumParameters () [ 0 ];
    }

    public static inline function position ( value : AnyAny ) {
        return value.enumIndex ();
    }

}

typedef Any2 = Of2<Dynamic, Dynamic>;
typedef Any3 = Of3<Dynamic, Dynamic, Dynamic>;

enum About2 <A, B> {
    PosA ( value : A );
    PosB ( value : B );
}
enum About3 <A, B, C> {
    PosA ( value : A );
    PosB ( value : B );
    PosC ( value : C );
}

abstract Of2 <A, B> ( About2<A, B> ) from About2<A, B> to About2<A, B> {
    @:from static inline function from_A <A, B> ( val : A ) : Of2<A, B> return About2.PosA ( val );
    @:from static inline function from_B <A, B> ( val : B ) : Of2<A, B> return About2.PosB ( val );
    @:to inline function to_A () : Null<A> return switch ( this ) { case About2.PosA ( val ): val; default: null; }
    @:to inline function to_B () : Null<B> return switch ( this ) { case About2.PosB ( val ): val; default: null; }
}
abstract Of3 <A, B, C> ( About3<A, B, C> ) from About3<A, B, C> to About3<A, B, C> {
    @:from static inline function from_A <A, B, C> ( val : A ) : Of3<A, B, C> return About3.PosA ( val );
    @:from static inline function from_B <A, B, C> ( val : B ) : Of3<A, B, C> return About3.PosB ( val );
    @:from static inline function from_C <A, B, C> ( val : C ) : Of3<A, B, C> return About3.PosC ( val );
    @:to inline function to_A () : Null<A> return switch ( this ) { case About3.PosA ( val ): val; default: null; }
    @:to inline function to_B () : Null<B> return switch ( this ) { case About3.PosB ( val ): val; default: null; }
    @:to inline function to_C () : Null<C> return switch ( this ) { case About3.PosC ( val ): val; default: null; }
}
```

Seems to work pretty well, but you have to call `Multimorph.value ( v : AnyAny )` to get the literal value. It can also give you the index of the type of the value, and is pretty readable with a static extension:

```
using Multimorph;

class Main {

    static function main () {
        trace ( func ( "Hello World!") );
    }

    static function func ( arg : Of2<Int, String> ) {
        if ( arg.position () == 0 ) {
            return 'Was Passed an Integer `${ arg.value () }`';
        } else {
            return 'Was Passed a String `${ arg.value ()}`';
        }
    }

}
```

[Here's a script](https://pastebin.com/kBMEsq14) that will make larger Multimorph packages.